# realloc is giving error - invalid next size

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int temp;


int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("input2.txt", "r");                      //Open the input
    int counter = 0; 
    int realloc_counter = 10; 

    int *line_array;                                    //Initialize the array
    line_array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));              //Allocate memory for initial ten numbers, of size int for each 

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp) > 0)
    {
        line_array[counter] = temp; 
        counter ++;

        if (counter % 10 == 0)
        {       
            realloc_counter = realloc_counter * 2;
            line_array = realloc(line_array, realloc_counter);
        }


    }



    fclose(fp);                                         //Close the input file
    free(line_array);                                   //Free the memory
```

The above code is what I have. It keeps giving me an error and I can't seem to figure it out. Using valgrind it says there is an invalid write of size 4. Any suggestions or insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "invalid next size" style of error message when using dynamic memory allocation is usually because you have corrupted the memory arena by writing beyond the end of an allocated buffer.

Have a look at your two allocation lines:

```
line_array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
line_array = realloc(line_array, realloc_counter);
```

The first is multiplying the element count by the element size so that the number of *bytes* allocated is correct. The second is just using the element *count* on its own without multiplying it by the element size.

So the first time you do a re-allocation, `realloc_counter` is set to 20, so you'll almost certainly *shrink* the memory allocated (though this depends on the relative sizes of your integers and bytes, of course).

For example, if `sizeof(int) == 4`, you first allocate the correct forty bytes, then reallocate twenty, when what you *need* is eighty.

What you *should* be doing is something like:

```
line_array = realloc(line_array, realloc_counter * sizeof(int));
```

---

As an aside, you should *also* be checking the return values from both `malloc` and `realloc` to see if they fail. It's not really a good idea to assume they'll always work.

Comment: Thank you so much. As soon as I read the part where you explain "The first is multiplying the element count by the element size so that the number of bytes allocated is correct. The second is just using the element count on its own without multiplying it by the element size." I went in, changed my code, it worked, I came back and read the rest of your answer I saw you did the same thing. I guess I was just overlooking my types.