# Invalid next size with realloc function

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, realloc

I have a dynamic structure and I'm trying to do a realloc to save new information on it, but when I tried to do it, it doesn't work...

I got this structure:

```
typedef struct {
    short int tipo;
    short int gravedad;
    char *mensaje;
    char *proceso;
    short int hora;
    short int min;
    short int seg;
}Info;

typedef struct {
    Info * info;
    int lenght;
}Logs;
```

I do a malloc in the main.c:

```
logs.info = (Info*) malloc (sizeof(Info*));
```

and this is the part where I'm trying the `realloc()`:

```
#define CHAR_1 1
...
read(fd, &c, CHAR_1);
if (c == '\n') {
    l->lenght++;
    int size = (l->lenght)+1;
    l->info = (Info *) realloc (l->info, sizeof(Info*)*size);
}
```

The first time `l->lenght` is 0.

The `compiler` says:

```
realloc(): invalid next size 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `l->info` NULL? If it is not, it must be a pointer returned by `malloc`. If that is the case then it is likely that you have corrupted the heap somewhere else on your program. `realloc` is complaining that the heap block for `l->info` is invalid.

Comment: @user3121023 I'm doing a malloc upside this part of code and I'm saving information on it correctly...

Comment: Is `l->info` supposed to point to a consecutive block of `size` `Info`s? If so, `sizeof(Info*)*size` should be either `sizeof(Info)*size` or `sizeof(*l->info)*size`. And as pointed out above, `l->info` should be `NULL` if using `realloc` the first time without an earlier `malloc`.

Comment: @HessianMad If you are doing an initial `malloc`, please show that code in the question. You may be allocating the block too small like you are for `realloc`.

Comment: I tried to use `sizeof(Info)` instead of `sizeof(Info*)` but doesn't work...

Comment: Lose the `CHAR_1`. If you're reading one `char`, `1` is not a "magic number".

Comment: Did you try `sizeof(Info)` for both the `malloc` and the `realloc`?

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried without * in the `malloc`and in the `realloc`

Comment: @HessianMad Then there is probably a buffer overrun somewhere in the code you haven't shown that is writing past the end of its allocated block of memory. Basicallly, you have corrupted the heap somewhere in your code.

Comment: have you set all to 0, you say you malloc but you need to initialize all struct members. memset( .. )

Comment: You have likely corrupted memory somewhere, possible dupe:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962390/realloc-is-giving-error-invalid-next-size

Comment: I revised my code once again and the problem was about what @IanAbbott said. I have to use `sizeof(Info)`.

Comment: @HessianMad It is better to make it `logs.info = malloc(sizeof *logs.info)`, that way you're safe if the type ever changes.

Comment: You should always include a 'tag' name on a struct, as that is what most debuggers use for displaying the individual fields of the struct

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  When calling `realloc`, always assign the returned value to a temp variable and check that temp variable for !NULL.  If/When `realloc` fails, the original pointer (if assigning directly to the target variable) will overlay the original pointer, resulting in a memory leak